# what's wrong with this simply 'buggy-sum' code?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I have an exam tomorrow, and this was an assignment question I got wrong.  I've been stuck on this for a while, can someone tell me what the solution is?

The problem is, how do you fix this code:

```
(define (buggy-sum lst)
  (+ (car lst) (buggy-sum (cdr lst))))

(buggy-sum (list 1 2 3 4))
```

My solution was as follows, but it's wrong:

```
(define (buggy-sum lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) '()]
        [else (+ (car lst) (buggy-sum (cdr lst)))]))

(buggy-sum (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Can someone tell me what the correct solution is?

Comment: Try: `cond [(null? lst) 0]` or `cond [(null? (cdr lst)) (car lst)]`

Comment: What happens what `(buggy-sum (cdr lst))` is `null?`

Comment: Do: `(apply + lst)` ;p (You should not assume `apply` will be slower than a naive solution) The given answer is correct however :)

Comment: @leppie Somehow I don't think that was the soln the prof wanted. ;) But would've been fun to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edge case is wrong. You're returning another null list if the list is null, and you should be returning an int. Simply replace `[(null? lst) '()]` with `[(null? lst) 0]`.